# Is there a better way to handle form tab order in PHP than this?

Tags: php, html

Is there a better way to handle form tab order in PHP than this?

I have a page with multiple repeated forms.  Due to the layout I want the tab order to be non-sequential, so I have to specify it in the html (so that I can specify it out of order).  My forms are constructed using PHP's block quote mechanism, which as far as I can make out doesn't allow arithmetic on PHP variables inside the block

I've implemented it, but my implementation seems awkward.  I can't help thinking there's a more elegant way to do this.

First I initialize some php variables at the top of the page.

```
$tab1=1;
$tab2=2;
$tab3=3;
$tab4=5;
$tab5=4;
```

Then later on, inside a php loop I do this...

```
$tab1+=5;
$tab2+=5;
$tab3+=5;
$tab4+=5;
$tab5+=5;
```

Then add the variables to the block quote...

```
$picshtml .= <<<BLOCK
<div class="addcomment">
    <a href="">Add Comment</a><br /><br />

    <div id="commentform$row[photoid]" class="commentform">
        <div id="submitanim$row[photoid]" style="display:none">
            <img src="loadingAnimation.gif" alt="Processing..." />
        </div>      
        <form action="">
            <div style="float:left;clear:left;text-align:right">
                Comment<br />Name <input type="text" id="name$row[photoid]" tabindex="$tab1" /> <br />
                Email <input type="text" id="email$row[photoid]" tabindex="$tab2" /><br />
                Website <input type="text" id="website$row[photoid]" tabindex="$tab3" /><br />
                <input type="button" value="Submit Comment" id="submit$row[photoid]" onclick="javascript:ajax($row[photoid])" tabindex="$tab4" />
            </div>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="comment$row[photoid]" tabindex="$tab5" ></textarea>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>

BLOCK;
```

Comment: If I had karma to edit this, I would help you. Instead of using the backtick notation for your code, try indenting your code lines with 4 spaces each.

Comment: Got the hang of it eventually... the backtick thing makes it hell to get right.  Instead I just used the button to add the 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `sprintf`?

```
$html = <<<BLOCK
...
<input type="text" tabindex="%d" />
...
BLOCK;

$order = 0;

$html = sprintf($html, $order, $order + 1, $order + 2, $order + 3, $order + 4, $order + 5, ...);

$order += 6;

// ...
```

Syntax reference here:

http://php.net/sprintf